# Possible to skip <-- nextpage --> tag in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm using pagination with wp_link_pages function and the <--nextpage--> shortcode.

I'd like to show the full post for certain users (without pagination) if they arrive without a "utm_source" value appended to the URL. Is there a way to "skip" the  shortcode for users without a "utm_source" value? Here's what I currently have:

```
if(!empty($_GET['utm_source']))
    {
        
        the_content();
    
        if ($page == count($pages)) { 
        ?>
        <p class="continue">Next</p>
        <div id="pagination_wrap">
            <a href="/">
                <div class="pagination_btn">Next</div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?
        }
        else
        { ?>
        <p class="continue">Continue Reading This Article</p>
        <?
        $defaults = array(
        'before'           => '<div id="pagination_wrap">' . __( '', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        'after'            => '</div>',
        'link_before'      => '<div class="pagination_btn">',
        'link_after'       => '</div>',
        'next_or_number'   => 'Next',
        'separator'        => ' ',
        'nextpagelink'     => __( 'Next' ),
        'previouspagelink' => __( 'Previous' ),
        'pagelink'         => '%',
        'echo'             => 1
        );
    
        wp_link_pages( $defaults ); 
        }
    }
    else {
        
        the_content();
    
    }
```